Android RecyclerView is not showing data
I am trying to fetch image details from local Api and show it using RecyclerView. Data are fetched successfully as i can see the log of Log.d("data", data.toString()) in logcat,  but are not displaying.
here is the source code of that activity:
lateinit var rvMain:RecyclerView
lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)
    rvMain = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
    setContent {

        rvMain.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
        rvMain.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)



        getAllData()

    }
}

private fun getAllData() {

    var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

    var retroData = retrofit.getData()

    retroData.enqueue(object :Callback<List<MyDataItem>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call:Call<List<MyDataItem>>,
            response: retrofit2.Response<List<MyDataItem>>
        ) {
            var data = response.body()

            myAdapter = MyAdapter(baseContext, data as ArrayList<MyDataItem>)

            rvMain.adapter = myAdapter

            Log.d("data", data.toString())
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<MyDataItem>>, t: Throwable) {
            //Log.d("data", "!!! ERROR in getting data !!!")
            t.message?.let { Log.d("data", it) }
        }


    })

}

Below is my adapter class's code:
class MyAdapter(var con  :Context,val list:ArrayList<MyDataItem>):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(v : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        var img = v.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.RV_Image)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(con).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        Glide.with(con).load(list[position].image_path).into(holder.img)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.count()
    }

}


You have to remove setContent {} function call.
When using Android Views, content of activity is set with setContentView(R.layout.activity_2) using layout id or view. Calling setContent is replacing your
activity_2 layout by ComposeView for jetpack compose UI and your original layout is detached from UI.
Your activity's onCreate should look like this:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2)
    rvMain = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)

    rvMain.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)
    rvMain.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    getAllData()
}

